# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, error on IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a MVC4 web application that works fine on Visual Studio 2012, using the local IIS Express Server. When I publish the application to an IIS 8 web server running on Windows 2012, the initial login page displays correctly. However, using remote debugging, I see that when I check the credentials using the following line:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
```

I get the error shown in the figure below:
[image: System.Web.Helpers error]
<sub>(source: [usf.edu](http://www.ismlab.usf.edu/capture.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 25):

Solution - Copy reference to local

1. Right click on reference System.Web.Helpers and select Properties
2. Change Copy Local to true.
3. Build Solution

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did read other responses mentioning that and I should have mentioned that. But I do not see System.Web.Helpers in the project references. WebMatrix.WebData is copied locally.

Comment: In my case "Copy Local" was already true. But for some reason (maybe because there were changes made related to nuget in the solution) the bin folder of solution on iis was not containing any .dll's including the System.Web.Helpers. When I Copied all the .dll's in that folder it started working. This may not be a solution but in case anyone faces this issue, First check whether .dll's are getting loaded in bin folder after building solution or not

Comment: Brilliant, I had a problem with Azure Webjobs and this was the error, finally this solution worked for me

Answer (score 25):

Sounds as though MVC has not been installed on the server.

Comment: Indeed, the standalone asp.net mvc 4 installer did it for me: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Comment: I copied my project to a new system (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015) and got this error. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 19):

**The `System.Web.Helpers.dll` is included in the official Nuget package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/).**

Install that and the references should be corrected, and the file should be copied to your bin folder.

Answer (score 16):

I was able to resolve this by downloading the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), searching for MVC and installing the "ASP.NET MVC3 (Visual Studio 2010 ) Released 4/11/2011" package. Close any Visual Studio instance prior to installing.

Comment: This approach worked for me as well on my build server. I installed ASP.NET MVC 4 using the Web Platform Installer as the reference error went away.

Comment: This worked for me to resolve this reference in VS2015.

Comment: This worked for me to resolve this reference is VS2017.

Comment: fix still good in 2021

Answer (score 8):

Make sure it's looking for the correct version of the file. Mine were incorrect, the web.config file was pointing to later versions than what I had in the project.

In the properties I noted the version was 2.0.0.0 so I made it this version in the web.config file

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just adding to the existing answers as even I ran into the same error and could not find the the reference in assemblies. I will just share what helped me:

Open package Manager from Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console and type:

```
PM> Install-Package microsoft-web-helpers
```

After this System.Web.Helpers will appear under References->Assemblies. From there the 'Copy local' property can be changed to True.

Answer (score 2):

I am running VS 2015Preview and could resolve the issue by installing the latest version of MVC via NuGet.

Just in case anyone is still coming across this one.

Answer (score 2):

I added "Microsoft ASP.NET Razor" using Manage NuGet Packages.

With Add References, for some reason, I only had System.Web.Helpers 1.0.0 and 2.0.0... but not 3.0.0.

Comment: Already had this installed and still getting this Reference error at Build time: warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem working with WCF service in IIS 8. Take a look at this solution [Deploying ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx/), it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something wrong with your **Web.config** file. 
Open the file and find the `<runtime></runtime>` tag.
modify the version of MVC.
For example, MVC 3

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Maybe is not an answer. You should use comments for that. And of course welcome to the StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

After adding the correct version of MVC, the reference to Microsoft Web Helper is added but not of System.Web.Helper.  Add this manually to your references.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and tried all of the same things to try to resolve it none of the answers above fixed this. I ended up manually copying the dll file from another project. Put it in the project/bin folder. Several of my extensions had this issue, I'm not sure what caused it.
[image: File added to the /bin folder]