# Empty API project has missing references

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using VS 2013 and choosing "ASP.NET Web Application" using .net 4.5.1, give it a name then choose the "Empty" template and check the "Web API" box only.

I've added a controller, test() method, built the solution and test in IIS and get error

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

If I use the built-in web hosting it works fine.

Current web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What version of .net framework is the Application being targeted in the IIS ? Maybe there is a version mismatch. Also, is copy local set to true for your assembly System.Web.Helpers?

Comment: 4.5.1 and System.Web.Helpers isn't even included in the project template. When I do include it, it thencomplains about missing the MVC dll

Comment: Check your `web.config`, it might be redirecting to the wrong version of that assembly.

Comment: Also have you checked this previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19462504/1260204

Comment: @igor I've tried several SO related posts, I don't even get that reference as part of my template but when I do add it, it's missing more.

Comment: No one can reproduce this?

Comment: @user3953989 - unfortunatly I do not have this vs version installed any longer. I did upvote your question though in the hopes it will get more traction. You can also try to edit the question and add additional details so it jumps back to the top of the list in the hopes someone else will see it that knows something more.

Comment: @igor thanks for the help!